# code can't find a file given relative path

Tags: python, path

Currently, I am working on learning Python. I followed a code from *a youtube video* and it seems to work fine on my personal computer, but when I tried it on the raspberry pi on VS code it does not find the file. It does produce an error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/My codes $ /bin/python "/home/pi/Desktop/My codes/Tutorial/read.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/My codes/Tutorial/read.py", line 2, in <module>
    assert os.path.exists("Pics/Dog.jpg")
AssertionError
```

This is the code:

```
import os
assert os.path.exists('Pics/Dog.jpg')
```

What can I do?

Comment: The formatting needs cleaned up

Comment: @sasha.c. Is Pics a folder?

Comment: `img` is empty. -- please review [mre] and [ask]. your question lacks the code for which you show an error message.

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i updated the question and added the code. Any help?

Comment: The Dog.jpg is not currently on "/home/pi/Desktop/My codes/Open CV Tutorial /

Comment: current working directory is `~/Desktop/My codes`, you're trying to access a relative path `pics/cat.jpg`, so it's trying to find `~/Desktop/My codes/pics/cat.jpg`. do you understand this? please learn about the "current working directory" and relative paths. -- please review [mre]. this doesn't require OpenCV. you can replicate this using **`os.path.exists()`**

Comment: you're on a system where it matters whether you look for a folder named `Pics` or `pics` (same for files). -- I've revised your question. your code didn't match the traceback you gave (Pics/Dog.jpg vs pics/cat.jpg but that didn't matter). please check that this simple 2-line code causes the assertion to fail. this is a [mre]. OpenCV is entirely superfluous in all of this. your issue isn't with OpenCV, it's with understanding how paths work.

Comment: The problem was the opencv library was not installed correctly, I wiped my OS on the raspberry pi and started over and installed opencv again with a different tutorial and it worked just fine. Thanks to everyone.